# On the proof of Schur's lemma in Fulton & Harris

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I'm reading the book on representation theory by Fulton and Harris. I'm stuck with the proof of Schur's Lemma 1.7:

> **Schur's lemma 1.7** If $V$ and $W$ are irreducible representation of $G$ and $\phi:V\rightarrow W$ is a $G$-module homomorphism, then
>   1. Either $\phi$ is an isomorphism, or $\phi = 0$.
>   2. [...]
>
> **Proof.**  The first proof follows from the fact that the kernel of $\phi$ and the image of $ \phi$ are invariant subspaces. [...]

I understand that a $G$-homomorphism is a synonym for a map between two representations.  I figured out why the kernel and the image are invariant (under any $g\in G$), by I have no idea why that fact leads to the conclusion.

I would be most grateful if you could fill in the gap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the kernel is an invariant subspace and $V$ is a simple representation, the kernel is $0$ or $V$.

Since the image of $\phi$ is an invariant subspace of $W$, it is either $0$ or $W$.

If $\phi$ is nonzero, then $\ker(\phi)=0$ and $Im(\phi)=W$.

If $\phi$ is zero, then $\ker(\phi)=V$ and $Im(\phi)=0$.

Comment: I've totally forgotten that the two spaces are irreducible :-(

Comment: @Pteromys That happens :)

Answer (score 1):

Since $W$ is irreducible under $G$, so the possible submodules of $W$ can only be either trivial module or itself, which are the only possible images of $V$.